# How to get travel time and link used from osm2po http service

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

I used osm2po to get shortest paths but I would like to get travel time and osm links ids used in the path. Is it possible?

Here is the osm2po service url format I use (this is an example):

http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService?cmd=fr&source=26915&target=106044&findShortestPath=false&ignoreRestrictions=false&ignoreOneWays=false&routerClassId=0&heuristicFactor=0.0&maxCost=0.0&debugExpansion=false&key=Key&value=Value&tsp=

Thanks!

Leo

Comment:
Well, I just found I can add format=geojson to the query string and I can then get the line strings associated with the path. Perfect. I then just need to match the id in the db with the travel speed.

Comment: @kaligrafy- It is ok to answer your own question.  It would be great if you could create an "Answer" for your own question that would detail what you did to get things working.  That will help future readers get through their own struggles with your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Added the following from user's own answer to mark as answered.

> Well, I just found I can add format=geojson to the query string and I
>   can then get the line strings associated with the path. Perfect. I
>   then just need to match the id in the db with the travel speed.